# Dividing class into groups

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

Just a question I have been pondering.

Assume you have a class of 100 students, each student chooses 3 friends. The goal is to split them into 4 groups of 25.

We define 'satisfaction level of student j', $ s_j=i/3$ where i is the amount of friends in the same group.

I'd like to find an efficient algorithm to split the class so that the average satisfaction is highest possible, and the number of students j with $s_j=0$ is lowest.

My initial thoughts were finding a way to use gale-shapely, or finding connected objects in a directed graph.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If a chooses b, does b also choose a?

Comment: Not neccessarily

Comment: What is that constrain with friends got to do with the task. The way you put the problem it is trivial to do. First choose 25 and then again 25 and at last again 25 people and you are done.

Comment: The idea is that every student will be in the group with as many friends possible.